# Synchronizing Data Between Two SQL 2008 Databases, via file, at a weekly interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am wanting to maintain a second copy of a MS SQL 2008 database for dev and testing. The production database is isolated for security reasons, but I can execute queries after-hours and move files to my dev machine via FTP.

Currently, I get a very large backup file from the DBA every 10-14 days. I completely drop my old DB and restore the new backup from scratch. I would like the interval to more like 2-3 days, but the process of restoring the whole DB takes too much time and effort.

Can someone please advise me on a better strategy to do this? Some sort of incremental system where I'm getting a smaller file that might restore quicker, and I can update more often?

Thanks in advance,

Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into SQL Compare & SQL Data Compare. I think this is exactly what you're looking for.

SQL Compare:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

SQL Data Compare:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/